# Why does my google font have inconsistent weight in multiple parts of the same character?

Tags: css, typography, google-webfonts, google-font-api

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I am looking to display the Google Font [Orbitron](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Orbitron) at consistent weights at every given font size. Sounds pretty easy, right? Not in my scenario. At certain `font-sizes`, some characters have multiple weights within the same character.

*Note: I am testing this in **Windows 7, Chrome v27***

**The Code:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
.sixteen{
    font-family: Orbitron;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.nineteen{
    font-family: Orbitron;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

<h4 class="sixteen">Home of Front End Developer and</h4>
<h4 class="nineteen">Home of Front End Developer and</h4>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/vHQjw/) to explain my issue. If you take a look at the fiddle, you'll see in the first line that the top line of the uppercase `F`, `E`, and `D` characters have more weight/thickness than the rest of the characters in that line. But as you'll notice on the next line, that

In case you cannot replicate what I'm seeing, here's a screenshot:

[image: Font sizes: 16px and 19px]

My question is two-fold:

1. What would the best way to technically describe this? 'Multiple font weights in one given character' lacks brevity, and isn't likely to have any valuable [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+fonts+multiple+font+weights+in+one+given+character).
2. Is there a way to fix this and make the weight consistent in every character at every font-size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you describe is as such just variation of the visible width of strokes in glyphs, or **stroke width variation** to put it briefly. Such variation is normal in serif fonts and also appears, at least to some extent, in many sans-serif fonts. However, in this case, the font is designed to have a rather constant stroke width, so the visible effect is caused by **font rendering differences**.
2. There is no way to remove the font rendering differences. Font rendering is a complex issue, and although some proposed or experimental CSS settings might affect some aspects of it, it’s basically outside your control. For example, font smoothing (also known as anti-aliasing) depends on the operating system and its settings as well as the browser and its settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this issue with a bunch of fonts used online when you go down to a certain size. It's the way the font is being anti-aliased.

You can see the same issue from Google showing off that font: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Orbitron

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this doesn't directly answer either of my questions.

Comment: @FillipPeyton Yes, it does. 1) It's call anti-aliasing. 2) Don't use that small of font size or use a different font that will work at that size.

Comment: Obviously, I could tell that a smaller font-size would 'fix' this, but I do not want to do this. Changing my requirements is not 'fixing' my issue. My second question was 'Is there a way to fix this and make the weight consistent in every character at every font-size?', so no, you did not answer that question.